# Who Writes Microsoft Support Articles? Can They Always Be Trusted?

Tags: c#

Here is an example of the type of article I'm talking about:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401

I assume these articles are written by people who work for Microsoft and that the code in the articles will always be rock solid and never contain any malicious code.  I just want to make sure I can explain to my boss that this is an ok place to copy code from (I've been told never to copy code from the internet, but this seems like a safe source).

Comment: If you can understand the sample code, you should be able to identify if there's anything 'malicious' in it, right?  You certainly shouldn't be adding anything you don't understand to your project.

Comment: Absolutely, but I am a lazy programmer.  If these articles can be trusted 100% of the time, I will test for functionality, and not take the time to understand each line of code.  I'm just trying to make a shortcut for myself (although not fully understanding code I implement can bite me in the ass later).

Comment: Nothing can be trusted, 0% of the time. You have to verify every line of production code no matter if Donald Knuth wrote it. You're not making a shortcut at all by not understanding the code. Furthermore, what you're doing may not be fully compliant with applicable laws (for example, SOX compliance may prevent you from doing this.)

Comment: @glowcoder - I certainly wouldn’t trust Knuth’s code. He doesn’t even test his code, he merely proves it correct. :D

Comment: I would like to point out that it is intentional from my previous comment that the following can be derived: 1) Code other developers write in your own shop cannot be trusted, and 2) Code you write cannot be trusted.

Comment: The premise is silly, there are thousands of industry wags that would have a field day with malicious Microsoft code for everybody to see.  They wish.

Comment: But sometimes on support sites they are just trying to demonstrate a concept for usage, not necessarily trying to write rock-solid production code, right?  I think this is OK and valuable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would trust them not to be malicious, but they're not always good code. (MSDN samples are sometimes pretty awful.)

For example, here's some code in the sample you gave:

```
compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare
    (listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text,
     listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);

// Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Ascending)
{
    // Ascending sort is selected, return normal result of compare operation
    return compareResult;
}
else if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending)
{
    // Descending sort is selected, return negative result of compare operation
    return (-compareResult);
}
else
{
    // Return '0' to indicate they are equal
    return 0;
}
```

Now, there are two issues here:

- Why is it deemed *valid* to have a comparer with no sort order? This should be a constructor parameter, validated at the point of construction IMO.
- You should *not* just negate the result of one comparison to perform a "reverse comparison". That breaks if the result of the first comparison is `int.MinValue` - because `-int.MinValue == int.MinValue`. It's better to reverse the arguments used to perform the original comparison.

There are other things I'd take issue with in this code, but these two should be enough to make my point.

I heartily agree with the other answers too, in terms of:
- Check the copyright / licence etc of any code you want to use
- Make sure you *understand* anything you want to use

Comment: They're not malicious but agreed the code can be sometimes just be flat out wrong.  The C# code seems to be ok, but the Visual C++ and MFC code can be downright bad in some places.  Take it with a grain of salt and always verify the code they're showing does what you want it to.

Answer (score 5):

Your boss probably wouldn't mind if you only copied the code into a **test project** that you use to test and understand the code. You can then use what you've learned to write the production code.

And while I don't think anyone outside of Microsoft knows the names of the people who write those support articles, they come from the same vendor that your toolchain does, so if you don't trust the support articles, then you can't trust the tools you've bought either.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Knowledgebase articles show safe (as in non-malicious but not necessarily secure) code, but usually the example provides the most basic use case possible. There's a good chance that you'll have to tweak the code a bit for it to work the way you want.

You should also pay attention to the date of the articles. For example, the article you link to is almost three years old. There's definitely a better way to handle that situation now.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that most codes in articles are there to help you understand the concepts. They are not "production ready". Learn the concepts instead and implement your own.

Comment: +1. There is also http://1code.codeplex.com/ project by Microsoft that tries to provide more "production ready" samples.

Answer (score 2):

Have you been told not to copy code from the internet because of rights issues?  If so then you don't have to worry about this Microsoft code.

I would advise you not to use any code you don't understand.  If you can't say if the code is malicious or not don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the note about whether it infringes on any rights to use Microsoft code, I was wondering about that too. +1

Answer (score 1):

MSDN and kb support articles are written by MS employees that are part of the given product's UX team (user experience). These are people who typically have a background in technical writing, but are not necessarily developers themselves (although some are). It's very common for the UX team to collaborate with developers on the product to ensure their code samples are correct. However this collaboration in my experience is one of the lowest priorities a typical MS developer has and can go ignored, and so it can at times lead to poor code getting out.

With that said, I completely agree with Carl Norum's comment. Copying code you do not understand is done at your own risk. Make sure you understand any code you place in your product!

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the Microsoft articles to be of the highest quality (sadly not their products).

However, there's always the danger of a spoofing site.

Comment: You must be used to horrible code.  MS code isn't the worst i've seen, but it's nowhere near "the highest quality".  It's almost always the bare minimum to demonstrate a concept, and almost always deliberately excludes error checking and even the most basic sanitizing of data.

Comment: I was describing the documentation which is different than the code.  However, many times to convey a complex idea, it is beneficial to "dumb down" an example.  It is a good way to communicate.

Comment: It can be, but you know people are going to try taking the code as-is and copying it into their projects.  (Evidence: *this very question*.)   There needs to be a really obvious warning that the code generally does not represent best practices (particularly re: security and error checking) and shouldn't be used without modification.

Comment: A disclaimer before each and every code snippet that it is for education rather than production?  I wouldn't care for that.

Comment: Me either.  But obviously *some* people just copy/paste the code and change a couple of variables.  Bad as it is, it's understandable -- they trust MS to use their own framework properly.  Even a comment like `// TODO: Add some error checking!` might be enough to let people know that the code is incomplete, and would show up in a number of IDEs' task lists to remind them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Explain that you carefully read the article to understand the information in there, and only copy code that you understand.

If you don't understand the code, then even if the code is correct it may not be doing what you actually need done, thus your program will be incorrect.

You also will have a hard time debugging and maintaining code if there are parts that you don't understand.